# Added Locale, matrix content not copied

Tags: localization

I am attempting to add a second locale to a site with existing content, much of that content in matrix fields.

Following the documentation for [Setting Up a Localized Site](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/localization-guide), I have defined the locale, enabled all sections for this locale (and the original one), set up the configuration and the index.php files. What I have not yet done is mark any field as translatable.

What I was expecting is that entries in the new locale would be initialized with content from the original locale. And this has happened, *except* that the matrix fields have not been duplicated, so the entries in the new locale do not have any of that matrix content.

This is very similar to [How do I get Matrix elements to copy their content across language Locales?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1709/how-do-i-get-matrix-elements-to-copy-their-content-across-language-locales). The answer there is "don't mark matrix fields as translatable", which I haven't done, so not sure why this isn't working for me.

Any clues?

Comment: Maybe it helps if you set one field of your entry type as translatable (not the Matrix), but this is just a guess.

Comment: @carlcs No, that didn't help: neither setting a different field in the entry type, or a sub-field in the matrix made any difference. The task to copy content across locales seems to run when you add a new locale, and when you save a section after enabling the new locale in that section. My `craft_content` table is multi-lingual, but the `craft_matrixcontent_xxx` ones are frustratingly not.

Comment: Marion, you're probably better off solving this directly with P&T. This other Q/A you're referring to got them to find a temporary workaround. Only that it doesn't work for you. Hopefully they can help you out or tell you that they fix the bug.

Comment: @MarionNewlevant This sounds like a bug. Can you please send us a ticket from your dashboard, so we can look into it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely a bug in Craft.  Doesn't just affect Matrix, but any relational field as well (Assets, Users, etc.)

It's not an super-easy fix, but as a workaround, you can re-save the entry in the original locale (before making any edits in the new) and the content will get duplicated over.

Comment: Can I use [ResaveAllElementsTask](https://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/tasks/ResaveAllElementsTask) to help with this?

Comment: Nope... that calls the ResaveElements task which is where the issue is.

Comment: So, has this been fixed? Because what is happening now, is that I make one of the asset fields in the matrix translatable, and the next time the element is saved (long after the locale was added), the translatable asset is now only set in the one locale.

Comment: Did you re-save the entry in the original locale first?

Comment: sequence of events: add locale, save multiple times in multiple locales, make asset in matrix field translatable, save in any locale (including the 'original') - and that asset is set only in the locale in which it was saved.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding that seems like a different problem than the original post, no?

Comment: Thought we might well be hitting the same bug, but since this isn't first save, the workaround isn't working. Has that been fixed?

Comment: The original issue hasn't been addressed, no. If you think this is a new bug, submit a ticket w/database and the steps to reproduce and we'll look into it.

Comment: I'm still experiencing the issue mentioned in the original question. Adding a new locale to an existing site doesn't copy over matrix content. On re-saving the original locale it does then copy over. Looks like the issue was fixed a while back though? https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/16

Comment: @LukePearce Only fixed for Craft 3 and not likely to be backported.

Comment: @BradBell Thanks for the fix. All the content is copied over BUT the Matrix fields. Is there a way even that gets copied over?