# Carry over asset field content to other locales

Tags: entries, assets, localization, assets-field

I have a site with English and French locales. One of the fields we have assigned to our entries is an asset field.  Currently when an admin adds a new entry, all the English content will carry over to the French locale except for the file selected in that asset field.  Ideally, I'd like for the English asset field contents to carry over to the French asset field and only change if the admin changes it in the French locale.

I have tried a variety of settings but haven't had any luck.  Any direction would be appreciated!

Comment: Chris, it might be worth checking over this question - https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/18511/locales-new-locales-not-copying-assets-across Perhaps this would solve your problem as well?

Comment: I saw that and tried updating the asset indexes but it didn't change anything.  Maybe I will keep playing around with different settings and updating the indexes and see if I can get the right combo.

Comment: You could use the `onAfterSave` event to fetch the entry in the English local and check its assets and store the same value in the French local when its saved the first time